# Search for hotels within a given radius for corresponding objects' locations (Gem Geocoder)

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, geolocation

I have 3 tables: `Objects`, `Locations`, `Hotels`.

Each object has several locations, and each location has several hotels (in 20 miles radius by default).

My models (a little bit simplified it to concentrate on the main things)

**object.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name

has_many :locations
has_many :hotels
```

**location.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name, :address, :longitude, :latitude

has_many :objects
has_many :hotels
```

**hotels.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name, :address, :longitude, :latitude

has_many :objects
has_many :locations
```

I want to create a search form, where user will be able to input Object's **name**, and **search radius**.

The output should be a list of all hotels, which are located within the given radius (less or equal to 20 miles) from the center of each location, which corresponds to object.

I want to use [Geocoder's](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem method `near`, but I am not sure how to build the controller layer of such task.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated side note: What tool(s) were used to produce the entity relation diagram above?

Comment: I used just Keynote. I usually draw every structure to better understand

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure as it looked unfamiliar. Nice work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a spatial-query-engine in your db to do these queries, e.g. MongoDB or PostGIS (in Postgres). I think the answer you're looking for will vary depending on which one you're using. I use PostGIS for this stuff and really like it.

That said, Geocoder can be used to power this internally without a spatial-query-engine, though it will be not-so-efficient. It will grind to a halt if you get really big. If you look at the source: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/stores/active_record.rb

```
# skeleton for the controller method
obj = Object.find(name)
locations = obj.locations
near_hotels = locations.map do |loc| 
  locations.hotels.near([loc.latitude, loc.longitude])
end
```

not sure the near method properly takes a radius argument, but you could write your own pretty easily by basically copying it:

```
# on the hotel class
def nearby(lat, lon, radius)
    options = self.send(:near_scope_options, lat, lon, radius, {})
    select(options[:select]).where(options[:conditions]).
      order(options[:order])
}
```

I strongly suggest you check out PostGIS.

Note, my example method produces a relation. You can narrow down your selection by scoping to just those hotels that match your object.

Comment: I know I did it late, but I checked out Postgis and it is very good.